# Post an image with HTTPClient but also some parameters on windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone, httpclient, multipartform-data

I want to do a `MultipartFormDataContent` request. But I also want to pass a lot of params with it. When I'm just doing a post I do this:

```
 public async Task<Webservice> inviteMembrs(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values)
        {
            String strUrl = String.Format("http://*****.com/nl/webservice/abc123/members/invite");
            var http = new HttpClient();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(strUrl));
            request.Content = new HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(values);
            var result = await http.SendRequestAsync(request);
            var data = new Webservice { Status = result.StatusCode };
            if (result.StatusCode == Windows.Web.Http.HttpStatusCode.Ok && result.Content != null)
            {
                data.Data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine(data.Data);
            }
            return data;
        }
```

This works perfect. But now I also want to pass an image with it. 
I found a lot of examples but always without extra params. 
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

content.Add(new StringContent(parameter), "name");

content.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "param", "filename");

HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(address, content);
```

Comment: Do I need to pass all the parameters that way or can I just give the List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> values as one param ?

Comment: This way you will post data in multipart-form format https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipart/form-data. I think you need to iterate through your collection to post all params